# Cesaro sum of positive numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove whether the Cesaro sum of the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\geq1}$ with $a_i\in [0,1]$ exist?

My intuition is that since the partial sums $S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ are bounded, we may have convergence. But since the partial sums are not monotonically increasing, we cannot use this. I can't find a counterexamples here for $a_i \in [0,1]$.

Any ideas/counterexamples would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint: choose $a_i$ to be $0$ or $1$ in such a way that the partial sums $S_n$ keep oscillating, and hence won't have a limit (choose $a_i$'s to be $1$ if you want to increase the partial sums, and choose $a_i$'s to be $0$ if you want to decrease it). You can actually even ensure that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=0$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=1$.

Comment: I tried this, but this gives a sequence of parial sums: $\{1,1/2, 2/3, 1/2, 3/5,1/2,4/7,1/2,5/9 \}$ having the limit 1/2.

Comment: I didn't say directly alternate between $0$ and $1$. You're allowed to do things like $1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$ and so on. Now compute the partial sums. So, a block of $1$'s, followed by a much bigger block of $0$'s followed by an even bigger block of $1$'s etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:\Bbb Z^+\to\Bbb Z^+$ where $0=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n+1)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^nf(j).$ Let $g(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n f(j).$

Consider a binary sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\Bbb Z^+}$ of a block of $f(1)$ consecutive $0$'s followed by a block of $f(2)$ consective $1$'s followed by a block of $f(2)$ consecutive $0$'s, etc. That is, if $i\le g(1)=f(1)$ or if $g(2n)<i\le g(2n+1)$ then $a_i=0,$ while if $g(2n-1)<i\le g(2n)$ then $a_i=1.$

Consider $m^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^m a_j$ when $m=g(n)$ for some (any) $n.$ If $n=2n'$ is even then

$$m^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^m a_j=g(2n')^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{g(2n')} a_j\ge$$
$$\ge g(2n')^{-1}\sum_{j=g(2n'-1)+1}^{g(2n')}a_j=$$

$$= g(2n')^{-1}\sum_{j=g(2n'-1)+1}^{g(2n')}1=$$ $$=g(2n')^{-1}f(2n')=$$ $$=\frac {1}{1+f(2n')^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{2n'-1}f(j)}$$

which $\to 1$ as $n'\to\infty.$

I leave the odd case $m=g(n)=g(2n'-1)$ for the reader to confirm that $g(2n'-1)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{g(2n'-1)}a_j\to 0$ as $n'\to\infty.$

For an example of a specific $f,$ let $f(n)=2^{(n^2)}.$ We have

$f(n+1)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^nf(j)=f(n+1)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{j^2}\le$

$\le f(n+1)^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}2^i=f(n+1)^{-1}(2^{1+n^2})=$

$=2^{-(n+1)^2}(2^{1+n^2})=2^{-2n}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.